# Update a div's contents on event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a select2 box that uses a remote search.  It works great.

When the user selects an item in the select2, I want to update a div on the page with the items's details.

I tried this, in my application.js - but render is not available in assets.

```
$('.category-search').on("change", function(e) {
   $('#job-items').html(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>  "jobs/items", :job_id => this.value) %>)
  });
```

What is the simplest, most railys way to do this?

Comment: So you would most likely need to make an Ajax call to fetch the content.

Comment: Make a `$.ajax` and pass the response to `$('#job-items').html()` in the `then`'s callback.

Comment: Your context is `$(this)`not `this` perhaps `$(this).val()`would do it

Comment: @t3__rry in the event handler `this` is referring to the JavaScript `this` and not to `$(this)` - `this.value` is perfectly fine. You only need to do `$(this)` yourself if you want to access jQuery specific properties or methods.

Comment: As the other's have said, `ajax` call would be needed because ruby is server side code and you are executing on the client-side. Ajax allows you to make the call to the server-side, passing `this.value` and similar if you need to and using the ajax callback you can then assign the return value to the DOM as 31piy said

Comment: @Nope Yes I thought he wanted to access his components through jQuery

Comment: thanks guys.  I have to use Ajax as pointed out.  Of course the JS is a static asset, ruby isn't available there.  (i'd hopefully added .erb to the extension).  So calling a controller and rendering the partial from there worked our well.